# The program unexpectedly exits when dragging the window and outputs 0xc000041d

Tags: c#, winapi, webview2

I am using [`webview2`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/) as UI.

When I use JavaScript to call C# dragging the window, there is a probability that it will exit unexpectedly.

C# Code:

```cs
public const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
public const int WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202;
public const int SC_MOVE = 0xF010;
public const int HTCAPTION = 0x0002;

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int wMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool ReleaseCapture();

public void DragMove()
{
    try
    {
        mainWindow.edge.IsEnabled = false;
        IntPtr hwnd = new WindowInteropHelper(mainWindow).Handle;
        Win32.SetCapture(hwnd);
        if (Win32.ReleaseCapture())
        {
            Win32.SendMessage(hwnd, Win32.WM_SYSCOMMAND, (IntPtr)(Win32.SC_MOVE + Win32.HTCAPTION), IntPtr.Zero);
        }
        mainWindow.edge.IsEnabled = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

JavaScript Code:

```js
window.chrome.webview.hostObjects.base.DragMove();
```

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: `0xc000041d` is [`STATUS_FATAL_USER_CALLBACK_EXCEPTION`](https://www.magnumdb.com/search?q=0xc000041d).

Comment: Not sure this applies here, but the documentation for [DragMove](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.dragmove) has the following: *"This method cannot be called when a window is hosted in a browser."*